# How to get values from date range picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, daterangepicker

I'm using the [Date Range Picker for Bootstrap](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) to select a range of dates, and everything looks good, my only problem is that after I have picked the dates and submit the form, I don't know how to get the values (dates) I have picked.

Below you can see my `daterangepicker` settings:

```
<input ui-jq="daterangepicker" ui-options="{
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      startDate: '{{ first }}',
      endDate: '{{ second }}',
      separator: ' til ',
      showWeekNumbers: true,
      locale: {
           applyLabel: 'Vælg datoer',
           cancelLabel: 'Annuller',
           fromLabel: 'Fra',
           toLabel: 'Til',
           firstDay: 1
      }
}" ng-model="plane.date" class="form-control" placeholder="Dato" />
```

As you can see I have tried to add `ng-model`, but still without luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

**Set it on apply event:** (don't forget the $scope.$apply part)

```
 angular.element('input#dataRange') = datePicker;
 datePicker.on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.fromDate = picker.startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    $scope.toDate = picker.endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                });
            });
```

**or get the values at any time:**

```
angular.element('input#dataRange')= datePicker;
$scope.fromDate = datePicker.data('daterangepicker').startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
$scope.toDate = datePicker.data('daterangepicker').endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

This is also useful if you want to get the date on loss of focus (blur) if the user edits the input manually:

```
datePicker.on('blur', function (ev) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.fromDate = datePicker.data('daterangepicker').startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                        $scope.toDate = datePicker.data('daterangepicker').endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    });
                });
```